# Nested TransactionScope in Rebus Eventhandler

Tags: .net, transactionscope, rebus

Rebus does not support DTC according to this: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Transactions but according to this  https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling Rebus does use a TransactionScope. I guess that means that a lightweight transaction is always used which cannot span multiple machines or connections.

In my case I want an EventHandler that first writes something to Firebird, then writes to RavenDB. Firebird and RavenDB are both capable of participating in a Distributed Transaction. But they are used within the TransactionScope created by Rebus.

Would I have to create a new nested TransactionScope with "Require New" in the EventHandler for Firebird and RavenDB to Commit together via the DTC. Or do I have to make a DTC implementation for Rebus for this to work.

As an alternative I will probably just have to make every write IdemPotent as suggested in the Rebus wiki.

I guess the question is more general than about Rebus. It is really about the behaviour of TransactionScope and promotion to DTC when some connections allow it and some does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are right that the question is more about how `TransactionScope` works, and to which degree Firebird and RavenDB are capable of enlisting in an ambient transaction.

Rebus does NOT (contrary to what the wiki stated at the time when you posted this question) handle messages inside a transaction scope by default.

It can be enabled, though - please check out [the updated wiki page](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling) for information on how to enable it.

I recommend that you either make your database updates idempotent, or that you split the write into two separate steps executed by two separate handlers.

Comment: Thank you. :) I am not sure why it would help splitting into two handlers ? I assume Rebus still does not use DTC if I enable TransactionScope as stated in your updated Wiki ? And then I still have the problem that the write to the database and the popping of MSMQ does not occur within the same Transaction. Which means that the writes will have to be IdemPotent no matter whether I split them into two handlers or not. Am I Right ?

Comment: If I use HandleMessagesInsideTransactionScope that you mention on the updated wiki page. Will Rebus escalate to use the DTC ? If not how did you stop this from happening :) As far as I know TransactionScope  escalates to the DTC when out of other options.

Comment: I guess it would escalate, because that's how that silly transaction scope works - but I believe some clever usage of e.g. `new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOptions.Suppress)` (if I remember correctly), could allow you to create another transaction scope that would not be enlisted in the Rebus' transaction scope.... but if you don't want that, why would you enable automatic transaction scopes in the first place?

Comment: I DO want it to escalate - although I like your idea of using idempotency, but I fear it will be too complex in our case. Its just that you said here https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Transactions that Rebus does NOT use DTC. So I was wondering if you had applied some secret magic sauce to TransactionScope to stop that from happening but you (luckily) have not.